# Codename One java jre version

Tags: java, eclipse, build, compiler-errors, codenameone

I´m trying to start developing with Codename One, I´ve already download the Codename One plugin for eclipse and it was successfuly installed.
The problem is that I can´t compile, I create a basic Codename One project (like the hello world one) and when I run test, the Build failes. It says something about the version of the CLDC.jar and the jre version, but I tried with java 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 and the same build error appears.
Should I change something in the build.xml ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is already solved by copying C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\lib\tools.jar to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext

Comment: This is a configuration issue : you're using the jre to compile, which do not work. Copying bits of the jdk to the jre location is not the right way to solve the issue.

Comment: Because my JAVA_HOME is pointing at jdk, and the compiler in my eclipse is also set to jdk...

Answer (score 1):

1)Make sure your plugin is up to date.
2)Make sure you have jdk installed not jre.

Comment: I downloaded the last plugin with eclipse tool and yes I´m sure it´s jdk installed not jre